# Is there a way to efficiently audit statistics attributes of objects in Java?

Tags: java, statistics

Say I have a class Person, and I created 10 instances of Person, and each person has several different attributes, such as `enum Gender{MALE, FEMALE}`, `enum Profession{CEO, POLICE, TEACHER}`, etc.

And I somehow have to randomly create many persons with random attributes and use a dedicated class to audit the statistics of created persons' attributes.

So, eventually, I need to generate a list of attributes with some statistics accordingly, such as, "`FEMALE: [number]`, `POLICE: [number]`,...".

Currently, I'm planning to add all kinds of the persons' attributes count, as a bunch of new attributes to the audit class, such as, "`femaleCount int`, `policeCount int`, ..." then manipulate the counts based on generated persons.

But, I got 10-ish attributes for each person, so I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: What do you need to produce as the result?

Comment: Create the `Audit Class ... maybe Singleton` with all desired statistics as parameters and just update `Audit object` as `Persons objs` are `created/updated or deleted`. All the time Audit object have to reflect the current statistic for allPersons

Comment: @PM 77-1 I need to output a list of all the occurrences of the created person's attributes as a string first.

Comment: Is your output a screen presented back or an object you need to pass to a different process?

Comment: @Traian GEICU Thanks, I think Singleton is a good idea to avoid adding all the attributes into a constructor, however, for this programming assignment of mine, somehow I am required to add a constructor to my Audit class.

Comment: @PM 77-1 I'm using a toString() method to return a list of all the results as a String, as my assignment specification required.

Comment: each Class have constructors, who said Singleton do not have one ? Singleton means one instance which can be generated based on a specific constructor ...

Comment: @Traian GEICU I'm sorry for the late reply and I see the usage of singleton now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is below, but do not say that it's the only one neither the best.
It's only depends of the purpose and your design.
Other option maybe it's to store all `Persons` in a data-structure `List` and just compute the statistic based on data at a certain time (have also update/delete here)

Version where only add is counting ...

```
public class Statistic
{
    
    private static Statistic s=null;
    public int countPerson;
    public int countMale;
    public int countFemale;
    public static Statistic getInstance()
    {
        if(s==null) 
            s =  new Statistic(0, 0, 0);
        return s;
    }
    public static Statistic getInstace(int cP,int cM, int cF)
    {
        if(s==null) 
            s = new Statistic(cP, cM, cF);
        return s;
    }
    //do whatever init wanted
    private Statistic(int cP,int cM, int cF)
    {
        countPerson = cP;
        countMale = cM;
        countFemale = cF;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Total="+countPerson+", Male="+countMale+", Female=" + countFemale;
    }
    
}
```

...

```
public class Person
{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Gender g;
    public Profession p;
    public enum Gender{MALE, FEMALE};
    public enum Profession{CEO, POLICE, TEACHER}
    Person(int id,String name, Gender g, Profession p)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.g = g;
        this.p = p;
        Statistic.getInstance().countPerson++;
        if(g.equals(Gender.MALE))
        {
            Statistic.getInstance().countMale++;
        }
        else
        {
            Statistic.getInstance().countFemale++;
        }
    }
    
}
```

...

```
public class TestStat {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //cPersons,cMale,cFemale - init
        Statistic.getInstace(10, 5, 5);
        System.out.println(Statistic.getInstance());
        new Person(1,"Male",Person.Gender.MALE, Person.Profession.TEACHER);
        System.out.println(Statistic.getInstance());
        new Person(2,"Female",Person.Gender.FEMALE, Person.Profession.CEO);
        System.out.println(Statistic.getInstance());
        
    }
}
```

Output

```
//custom start from (10,5,5) based on Singleton Custom Constructor
Total=10, Male=5, Female=5
//start update counters
Total=11, Male=6, Female=5
Total=12, Male=6, Female=6
```

Thinking twice maybe it's better to keep a `List` with `Persons` on `Singleton`
and make each time a `new Computation` - from `Singleton` instead on `Person`.
About `Delete` a person which can be translated in "moving from a Company to other" and then it's not to be reflected on Statistic.

Even so, on current you could add a `delete method` on person which could be reflected with adjust `Statistic` with `minus` and `Person-Instance` with `null`.

Further, it's up to you to update design as wanted.